# HTML5 Drag & Drop: Source element moves to end after it is cloned

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have setup a basic script that allows me to drag an image from one column to another, cloning it in the process. This functionality works, and the element is cloned, but once the element is dropped, the original element moves from its position in the DOM to the bottom of the container.

How can I stop this from happening? I would like the source images to stay in position after they have been cloned.

The script I am using is below:

```
<script>

        var clone;
        var cloneId;

        function dragStart(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.effectsAllowed = 'copy';
            ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
            ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target, 0,0);

            clone = ev.target.cloneNode(true);
            cloneId = ev.target.getAttribute('id');
            clone.className += ' ' + 'selected';
            ev.target.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

            return true;
        }

        function dragEnter(ev) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return true;
        }

        function dragOver(ev) {
            return false;
        }

        function dragDrop(ev) {
            var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
            clone.className += ' ' + 'cloned';
            clone.id = cloneId + '_cloned';
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
            src.removeAttribute('draggable');
            ev.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

    </script>
```

The draggable elements have the following markup:

```
<img src="images/module_image-12.png" alt="Full width image" id="module_1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">
```

Here is a working example of the issue: http://codepen.io/AlxTheRed/pen/jBLQRj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Had to change this line:

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
```

to

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(clone.id));
```

So, I was trying to get the ID of an entire object, rather than the ID of the object. It now works as intended.